# MvvmCross - Does Localization work in DataTemplate?

Tags: internationalization, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I'm developing a Win Store App with MvvmCross. I have some problems with internationalization technique when I have to apply it to a DataTemplate of a GridView or ListView. In these cases it seems it uses only the FallbackValue.

In the same view other TextBlocks are correctly translated, so I think that the Json file is ok. Here a sample of TextBlock that is not translated:

```
<TextBlock mvx:Bi.nd="Text TextSource, Converter=Language, ConverterParameter=Name, FallbackValue=TestName" />
```

Has someone already faced this problem?

Comment: Aside - there is an `Mvx:La.ng` helper which can make the i18n bindings simpler to write - it uses the same syntax as `local:MvxLang` in Android - e.g. see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Babel/Babel.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml#L40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - i18n does work inside DataTemplates... **BUT** each template uses its DataContext as its `TextSource` so you need to expose a mechanism to get to the individual items in your list to also expose the TextSource - just like the VMs do. ListItem wrapping techniques - like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22696529/373321 may help with this.