# How to Bind Button Inside Collection View Cell in MVVMCross Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am unable to find the solution of my problem. I want to bind a button inside a collection view cell to my View Model.e.g My view Code is

```
VideoQueueCollectionView.RegisterNibForCell(QueueItemCell.Nib, QueueItemCell.Key);
var source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(VideoQueueCollectionView, QueueItemCell.Key);
VideoQueueCollectionView.Source = source;

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<VideoQueueView, VideoQueueViewModel>();

set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.VideoTrailers);
set.Bind(source).For(b => b.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.ViewVideoTrailerCommand);
set.Apply();
```

And My Collection View Cell Code looki like that

```
public QueueItemCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.DelayBind (() => {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<QueueItemCell, DeviceQueueItem> ();
                set.Bind (SourceNameLabel).To (vm => vm.SourceDeviceName);
                set.Bind (ReceivedTimeLabel).To (vm => vm.ReceivedTime);
      set.Bind (ButtonCross).To (????????);
                set.Apply ();

                SetFont();
            });
        }
```

Because My Command is in VideoQueueViewModel. How I can bind this Command. I am stuck in this issues from past 2 days

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your viewmodel into the row model. That way you can access the command that is on the viewmodel. This issue is also discussed in: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/35

and: [How to binding list item to whether it is contained in another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695039/how-to-binding-list-item-to-whether-it-is-contained-in-another-collection)