# WrapConverter for Binding item click in ListView template MvvMCross

Tags: android, listview, binding, mvvmcross

I have read this question
[Binding button click in ListView template MvvMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075928/binding-button-click-in-listview-template-mvvmcross)
Here is the code:

```
public class ListPresentationViewModel: MvxViewModel
    {
    private readonly ISQLService _sqlSvc;

    public ListPresentationViewModel (ISQLService sqlService)
    {
        _sqlSvc = sqlService;
        MenuCollection = WrapConverter.ConvertToWrapperClass(_sqlSvc.MenuItemGetAll (), this);
    }

    private List<MenuItemWrap> _menuCollection = new List<MenuItemWrap> ();
    public List<MenuItemWrap> MenuCollection {
        get{ return _menuCollection;}
        set {
            _menuCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => MenuCollection);
        }
    }

    private IMvxCommand _orderBtnClick;
    public IMvxCommand OrderBtnClick{
        get{
            _orderBtnClick = _orderBtnClick ?? new MvxCommand<MenuItemWrap> (btnClick);
            return _orderBtnClick;
        }
    }

    public void btnClick(MenuItemWrap item)
    {
        MenuCollection.Clear ();
    }
}
```

And I would like to know about the WrapConverter class.

Is it customized or standard library class?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a custom class. There are also other ways to accomplish this behavior: for example with using a value converter that wraps your list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom class. The cause for this issue is explained in this issue: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/35

An explanation of the solution for this using a wrapper is: [MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview)

There are also other ways to accomplish this behavior: for example with using a value converter that wraps your list: [How to binding list item to whether it is contained in another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695039/how-to-binding-list-item-to-whether-it-is-contained-in-another-collection)